# How to write an animation with javascript canvas without clearRect function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a webpage that contains a canvas object, I should make an animation of a figure pictured by canvas.
On the same area I already have other figures pictured, so I can't use the drawRect function to erase the figure in each loop of the animation. How can I resolve?

**Complete code of my webpage:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Animazioni con canvas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stile.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="codice.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas">canvas not supported.</canvas>
<script>
let mycanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
let ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
mycanvas.width = 600;
mycanvas.height = 400;

ctx.fillStyle = "greenyellow";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100);

const step = 5;
let x = 0;

let loop = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke(); 
  x = x + step;
  x === mycanvas.width + 50 && (x = -50)
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm beginner with the html,css and javascript technologies. I tried different solutions, looking for them on the internet, but I don't know how to proceed, so ask in this website how to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: You have to clear canvas and then paint every figure in every frame

Comment: @Konrad thank you for the answer. I know that to paint the figure in every frame, have to clear the canvas continuosly. But this operation is difficult in my code, because I wrote in the questions only one page of the website, and in this page is easy, but in the other canvas on the other pages, I have a background fixed in the canvas, and a javascript function that contains a for-cycle which contains the paint of the figures. Each figure should have an animation. So, I can't erase the background and the objects already drawn.

Comment: There is no other way. You could use webgl but it's much harder

Comment: could you clear a smaller rect of just the area that needs to be redrawn? There are also ways to clear the area within a path. Could that work for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here are three potential ways of not having to redraw everything. Which one works best for you will depend upon everything else you need to do with the canvas. In each example, there's a background, which is a gradient, and four figures. The bottom right figure is animated and redrawn every frame, the others are not.

The first is in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfu309yt/1/). It creates a clipping rectangle around the anmiated figure:

```
context.beginPath();
context.rect(figureCenter - figureSize, figureCenter - figureSize, figureCenter * 2, figureSize * 2);
context.clip();
```

By doing that it can call the drawBackground function, which would overwrite everything in the canvas, but only the part of the background behind the figure (inside the clipping rect) is redrawn. Then the animated figure is then drawn. The other figures do not have to be redrawn.

So you can redraw everything that might be in the area you want to update, without worrying that anything that would be drawn outside the updating area. The clipping area does not have to be a square.

The second example is in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zco1dye/). It has two canvas elements overlaid. The bottom one has the background and the top contains the figures. This allows it to clear the rect around the area that is animated without erasing the background.

```
context.clearRect(figureCenter - figureSize, figureCenter - figureSize, figureCenter * 2, figureSize * 2);
```

By using layers like this, you can put animated things on one canvas and static things on other canvases.

Finally there's [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23ubxrjn/). It uses an OffscreenCanvas, and everything that isn't animated is drawn to it, then the contents of the offscreen canvas are redrawn to the visible canvas every frame:

```
context.drawImage(offscreenCanvas,0,0);
```

With this method you can store drawn things to reuse in later frames.

This answer is longer than I intended, but there's no one solution that is best in all situations.